# when i click on a button i put in my recyclerview adapter it affects all the rows

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

The holder.accept button returns the same result for all clicks i want it to return a different value wen i click on the other buttons in the other items in the recyclerview

[image]

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Delivery product = productList.get(position);
    Glide.with(mCtx)
            .load(product.getImage())
            .into(holder.imageViewx);
    holder.testsname.setText(product.getSendername());
    holder.testsphone.setText(product.getSenderphone());

    holder.testitemname.setText(product.getItemname());

    holder.testitemlocation.setText(product.getItemlocation());
    holder.testdlocation.setText(product.getDeliverylocation());
    holder.testrphone.setText(product.getRphone());
    holder.testdate.setText(product.getDate());
    holder.testtime.setText(product.getTime());
    holder.Textdelivery.setText(product.getDeliveryno());
    rider=holder.Textdelivery.getText().toString();
   // rider=holder.testsphone.getText().toString();
    //holder.accept.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Request Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, rider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            uploadImage();
        }
    });
}
```

//this is my upload method
        private void uploadImage() {

```
    ApiInterfacer apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterfacer.class);
    Call<img_poja> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(rider);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<img_poja>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<img_poja> call, Response<img_poja> response) {

            img_poja img_pojo = response.body();
            Log.d("Server Response", "" + img_pojo.getResponse());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<img_poja> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Server Response", "" + t.toString());

        }
    });
```

Comment: Instead of putting the code snapshot rather share the code.

Comment: thanks  i just did that...i have three items in my recyclerview and each has a button and is supposed to return a different value for each but when i click on all the buttons it returns the same value.i think the buttons are only affecting one item

Comment: Can you share your uploadImage() function? How do you know that same value is returned?

Comment: am using a post to send the string rider to a php update function but am just using the toast to check if i press the button it gives me the corresponding rider values but its giving me one for all the clicks

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

> final Delivery product = productList.get(position);

If you are not changing the value of

> product.getDeliveryno()

Pass product.getDeliveryno() value in uploadImage as parameters.

```
holder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Request Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, product.getDeliveryno(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            uploadImage(product.getDeliveryno());


        }
    });
```

and uploadImage Method modify with

```
public void uploadImage(String rider){

    ApiInterfacer apiInterface = 
        ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterfacer.class);
        Call<img_poja> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(rider);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<img_poja>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<img_poja> call, Response<img_poja> response) {

                img_poja img_pojo = response.body();
                Log.d("Server Response", "" + img_pojo.getResponse());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<img_poja> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Server Response", "" + t.toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @TundeNiiKal'el ok great :)